# Error displaying the active state of bootstrap pagination

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to display pagination on my pages but I have an issue. I want to use the bootstrap active class to show the current page but I don't know how to go about it.

When I add the active class (as shown in the code below), all the links become active. Please what do I do?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 6; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM offers ORDER BY i.id ASC LIMIT $start_from, 6";
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM offers"; 
$rs_result =  $db-> query($sql2, array('id' => $_SESSION['id'])); 
$row = $rs_result->fetch(); 
$total_records = $row[0];
echo $total_records;
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 6); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {                 
            ;echo"
             <ul class='pagination'>
              <li class='active' ><a href='myoffer.php?page=$i' >$i</a></li>      
            </ul>
             ";
   };
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a condition that tells which page is currently being displayed (based on the value of the query string 'page', also you should put the echo `<ul` line before your loop:

```
echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 

    if ($page == $i)
           echo "<li class='active' >";
    else
           echo "<li>";

    echo "<a href='myoffer.php?page=$i' >$i</a></li>";
};
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: You are welcome. Kindly mark it as 'accepted' so others can tell this is the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of Aram Tchekrekjian's answer

```
($page == $i) ? "<li class='active' >" : "<li>";
```

Even better than that is to have the ternary operator inside of the `<li>`
 tag and task it with echo `class ="active"` portion. So it would look like this

```
<li <?php ($page == $i) ? class="active" : false;?>>1</li>
```